# C# example for Google Checkout replies?

Tags: c#, google-checkout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# and Google Checkout - getting the reply back from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321465/c-and-google-checkout-getting-the-reply-back-from-the-server)

Sorry for the re-post but this question seems to be a bit of a "white whale" for me. I simply can't find any C# examples of how to handle the transaction reply from Google Checkout:

Are there any tutorials out there on how to get the responses back from a Google Checkout transaction when using C# and the GCheckout API? All of the examples I could find were for previous versions of the API and not the current one (2.5). More specifically, I'd like to see an example reply of what Google will post back to me *without* an HTTPS connection. I know it's minimal data, but I'd still like to see an example of it and see how others are parsing it.

Comment: If your question is seeing low activity, you can try placing a bounty on it, adding additional information or sharing links to it in other communities that may be able to help you. I've closed this as a duplicate.